# jQuery gathering inputs without submit

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get values from inputs without any action from user and then save it via php to txt file.

This is what I got so far:

```
var x = setInterval(function() { 
var email = $("#test").val();    
if(email != '' && email != newemail) {

     $('#display').append(email)

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'inputs-saving.php',
      data: ({usremail:email}),
      success: function(data) {     
      }
    }); 

}
var newemail = $("#test").val();
}, 1000);
```

it works almost fine, but I need to check if value changed, because if I input some text it will be constantly writen in file every second.

I have also tried to add something like "var newemail = email", but can't make it work corectly.

Comment: Why not use onchange ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$('#test').on('change',function () {
    var email= $(this).val();
    if(email != '') {

        $('#display').append(email);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'inputs-saving.php',
            data: ({usremail:email}),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Here `test` is the email filed id.
I thing it will help you.

Comment: damn can't upvote u yet but it is exactly what I want! Thank you !

Comment: Okay you can accept my answer by click on the right button :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    //place your logic
});
```

blur will not trigger every time you change the text, only when you remove focus from that box

Answer (score 0):

There is variable scope problem , Try this:

```js
var newemail = '';
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var email = $("#test").val();
  if (email != '' && email != newemail) {

    $('#display').append(email)

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'inputs-saving.php',
      data: ({
        usremail: email
      }),
      success: function(data) {
         currentemail = email;
      }
    });
  }
}, 1000);
```